# how to select month and year in from dd/mm/yyyy 00:00 format mysql

Tags: mysql

I have datetime in mysql as 20/09/2016 10:00

How can I select only month and year?

I have tried multiple things suggested but not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  `date_format()`.

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: i have tried : select date_format (column1, '%m/%Y') from table1, returns null value

Comment: what's the datatype of that column?

Comment: varchar, which type should it be and how to i change it?

Comment: If you store only the date part then the type should be `date` and if you store the date and time then it should be either `timestamp` or `datetime`

Comment: Dates should always stored as it is not as varchar. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: ALTER TABLE table1
CHANGE column1  DATETIME , i am getting an error when trying to change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing the right datatype has much gravity.

Since you are storing date time in `varchar` datatype I would suggest to move it to the `timestamp` type.

But before that you need to change the format of your date time value in a standard one (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`).

First, update the date time values to the above format:

```
UPDATE 
your_table 
SET column1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

Now change the datatype to `timestamp`

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY column1 timestamp;
```

---

Now execute your query:

```
select date_format (column1, '%m/%Y') from table1
```

Comment: Hi, in your suggestion about "SET column1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')", it changed all my dates to today's date. how to i keep my original dates?